# Is there a nonparametric test available in R to test for a trend in a binary variable?

Tags: r, time-series, binary-data, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, test-for-trend

I have e.g. the following (n=14) time series data: 0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0

By looking at this time series, it is easy to see that in the first half we have more zeros than ones and in the second half more ones than zeros. Therefore, it is quite probable that there is a trend from value 0 to value 1 in these observations.

I have already found the u Test which allows me to test for this trend, but it requires a table to look up the p-value. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Illustration_of_calculation_methods)

My question now is, if there is any test for this issue (already implemented in a R package) which doesn't require a table to look up p-values. The reason for this is that I am creating a web application (with shiny) that should be as easy to use as possible.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What kinds of trends are possible? Will the trends always be 'smooth' & monotonic? Are the temporal intervals equally spaced? Are autocorrelations possible? (BTW, the Mann-Whitney U-test is implemented in R, & doesn't require you to look up values in a table--see [?wilcox.test](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/wilcox.test.html)--but asking about R code is off topic here.)

Comment: Check out the "runs test"

Comment: @gung Thanks for the hint about the implementation in wilcox.test: You're absolutely right (see my solution below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to test whether the proportion of 1s changes with time. The simplest model would be a logistic model against time, i.e., against an increasing indicator variable:

```
yy <- c(0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0)
model <- glm(yy~seq_along(yy),family="binomial")
summary(model)
```

If you are only interested in whether the time coefficient is significant, you can look at the `coefficients` field of the `summary` output:

```
summary(model)$coefficients[2,4]
```

Of course, if you want to include whether the proportion is increasing or decreasing, you may want to also look at the sign of the coefficient:

```
summary(model)$coefficients[2,1]
```

Comment: The p-value in the coefficients table wouldn't be valid though if the data were autocorrelated, right?

Comment: @gung: quite so. But to be honest, I don't think you could meaningfully detect autocorrelations (and distinguish it from a trend!) in $n=14$ observations of binary data.

Comment: That's a good point. Couldn't an autocorrelation-consistent variance-covariance matrix be used though? Or is it still mostly pointless w/ N=14?

Comment: @gung: it probably could. But for $n=14$, I think it would be of questionable utility even for continuous data. For discrete data, and specifically for *binary* data, I think it *is* pointless. (I recently looked at autocorrelations for low volume count data time series with a few hundred data points, and that was already futile. Much more with only $n=14$ and binary data. There is a reason why INARMA models are few and far between.)

Comment: Hmmm, that might make for an interesting question.

Comment: @gung: post away! Something that I found to be somewhat related is [Mona Mohammadipour's 2009 Ph.D. thesis "Intermittent demand forecasting with integer autoregressive moving average models"](http://eprints.bucks.ac.uk/1406/). I don't think it ever appeared anywhere in article form, and I haven't been able to find a decent publication on INARMA modeling, so anything you would like to post would be helpful.

Comment: I would be *asking*, Stephan, not answering.

Comment: I did ask a new question (cf. [Is autocorrelation not worth addressing with small N?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/222278/7290)) Feel free to edit it, if I've missed something.

Comment: Could I use mann kendall trend test as well? `trend::mk.test()`. I think that this would be a NP version of your answer and less powerful.

Comment: @GuilhermeParreira: that does sound like it would be a possible approach, good point!

Answer (score 0):

I did it as gung supposed with wilcox.test.

```
output$wilcoxon <- renderPrint({
d <- dataReader()
e <- subset(d, d[,2]==0)
f <- subset(d, d[,2]==1)
g <- wilcox.test(e[,1],f[,1], paired=FALSE, alternative = "two.sided")
cat('p = ',round(g[[3]],3))})
```

Thanks again for your help!