# Is autocorrelation not worth addressing with small N?

Tags: regression, time-series, autocorrelation, covariance-matrix, small-sample

Consider a simple regression context in which there is a small set of response values, $Y$, and corresponding dates, $X$.  (For simplicity, we can assume the dates are equally spaced.)  We would like to regress $Y$ onto the time variable, but there may be autocorrelations that would make the standard errors / $p$-values, etc., invalid.  One approach would be to use an autocorrelation-consistent variance-covariance matrix for the betas and construct SEs and tests manually from it.

My questions are:

1. Can it be the case that this just isn't worth it?  How does the value of this vary as a function of $N$ and the magnitude of the autocorrelations?
2. Does the distribution of $Y$ matter (e.g., if the data are conditionally normal, vs. binomial, vs. Poisson)?
3. Would it make a difference if the true data generating process had an MA term but no actual AR terms?

<sub>For context, this thread comes from the discussion in comments here: [Is there a nonparametric test available in R to test for a trend in a binary variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/221972/)</sub>

Comment: What do you mean by small?

Comment: For small n I don't really see the value of HC/HAC errors - they only have an asymptotic justification, and this is ruled out in this setting

Comment: I think that if the sample wasn't small you'd be talking about harmonics like Fourier etc. to start with. You wouldn't be thinking about HAC or AR models. These come up in relatively small samples. So, unless you're talking about 5 observation samples, autocorrelations are something to worry about

Comment: @Tim, this question was prompted by a conversation linked at the bottom. In that context, the N was 14. I am open to a somewhat-arbitrary, heuristic cutoff, or a series of shades-of-gray cutoffs, if that is convenient for potential answerers.

Comment: corrections for SEs work good in general for relatively large samples. For small samples - which are rare encounters nowadays - you are hopeless in doing accurate analysis whether you correct for this or the other shortcoming. In small sample you can just do good if you know some good distributional stuff.